# Unicode in the SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode

The datatable received from the stored procedure contains a XML column. That XML column contains unicode data (For example: 顾客名称). Since the literal in the XML is not prefixed with N'. How to get the unicode data and store it in a variable?

Comment: `Since the literal in the XML is not prefixed with` what string? A hard-coded one in the stored procedure? A string in a dynamic SQL string? Parameters don't need prefixes, so if you use parameterized queries instead of dynamic SQL you should have not problem. If you use hard-coded strings, you *have* to prefix them.

Comment: BTW this page is Unicode, stored in a `nvarchar` column in SQL Server, using parameterized queries. It had no problem storing and displaying your question, *precisely* because it doesn't use dynamic SQL

Comment: I'm unclear what you are asking. The data is already in XML that is returned by the stored proc and contains `顾客名称`? What is your attempt to get this from the XML, into a variable that isn't working?

Comment: While parsing the XML and storing the info in the respective columns of the temp table, the unicode gets  changed to '???'..

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add **N** before the XML Column just below & Assign this value to a Variable.

```
DECLARE @XML XML=N'顾客名称' --Add your Column Name
SELECT @XML 

DECLARE @XML NVARCHAR(50)=N'顾客名称'
SELECT @XML
```

**Inserting**

```
INSERT INTO TableName ([Col_Name]) VALUES (N'<Value>')
```

**XML Parsing**

```
DECLARE @XML_ XML=N'<Event><Name><Action>顾客名称</Action></Name></Event>' -- add "N" here

SELECT T.item.value('(Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Unicode]
FROM @XML_.nodes('/Event') AS T(item)
```

---

Using Table Insertion

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (         --- Creating 1st Tables
[NAME] NVARCHAR(255))

DECLARE @AnotherTable TABLE (   --- Creating 2nd Tables
[2nd Table NAME] NVARCHAR(255))

DECLARE @xml_ XML=N'<Event><Name><Action>顾客名称</Action></Name></Event>' -- add "N" here

INSERT INTO @T                 ----Inserting Data into 1st Table
SELECT T.item.value('(Name)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
FROM @XML_.nodes('/Event') AS T(item)

SET @xml_=(SELECT NAME FROM @T FOR XML PATH('Columns'), TYPE)

INSERT INTO @AnotherTable      ----Inserting Data into 2nd Table
SELECT T.item.value('(NAME)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
FROM @XML_.nodes('/Columns') AS T(item)

SELECT * FROM @T
SELECT * FROM @AnotherTable
```

---

Comment: Or use parameterized queries, the way SO itself does

Comment: Consider the XML has the the data <ACTION>顾客名称</ACTION>. While parsing and saving it to the temp table, the Unicode is changed to ???. Even though the column of the temp table is of the datatype NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: Thank you for your response. However it still didn't answer my query.  Here is what I am looking for; How to prefix XML data with N in the below case?

 DECLARE @XML AS XML
 
 SET @XML= (select 'Table1' AS [Table]
  (SELECT Column1 FROM INSERTED FOR XML PATH('Columns'), TYPE) 
    FOR XML PATH('ROOT'), TYPE)
    
 INSERT INTO AnotherTable(XMLDATA) VALUES (@XML)

Comment: @user2746800, add that code you've tried (which looks like a trigger) to your question. Include the CREATE TABLE statement. Details like data types are important.

Comment: @user2746800 - I had edited the code now. Plz Check . Just assign the value to XML Data type Variable is enough. No need to add the literals here. Just Check now Edited code under the **Using Table Insertion** tag

Comment: @user2746800 - Did u try this?

Comment: After analyzing found that when the data is transfered from a Console application to the WCF Service, the characters are changing to ??. Which is why modifying the Stored procedure data type did not fix it. Below is a sample of the code;                 string strData = ToStringAsXml(dsExportData);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData); Encoding.ASCII doenot support multi languages and Unicoding.Unicode didn't work for me as the data contains encoded HTML string

Comment: @Thiyagu - Thank you for all the inputs. Finally worked by changing from Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stringData) to Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringData)